# ListAgg() ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence

Tags: oracle

I'm running a query where I don't want to include the GL column in the GROUP BY clause because I don't want to show a different row for each variation of the GL field. But I need to evaluate the field in subsequent processing, comparing it to a list of dynamically generated GL numbers. The best way I can think to do this is with a function and I'm trying ListAgg(). First off, is there a better function to use to compare the GL from each row to a list? Also, I am able to get the results below using SQL Developer, but not when I try to output it on a web page where Oracle returns a ORA-01002 error. We are using 12c in both cases. Below is the query and the output. Without ListAgg(), I have to include the GL column in the SELECT and GROUP BY and it undesirably outputs a separate row for each GL.

```
SELECT h.h_spa_id as spa_id,
       h.submit_dt,
       h.oa_ap_date,
       ListAgg(gl,',') within group (order by gl) "mygl"
 WHERE h.next_apprv= 'approverID'
   and h.table1_id = d.table2_id
   and h.table1_id = table3_id
 group by h.h_spa_id,h.submit_dt,h.oa_ap_date
 order by h.h_spa_id

H_SPA_ID    SUBMIT_DT               OA_AP_DATE                        MYGL
1627005    1/25/2008 10:11:53 AM   1/25/2008 11:15:56 AM      52287,52287,52287,52287,52287,52287,52287,52287,52287,52287,52385,52385,52385,52385,52385,52385,52385,52385,52385,52385,52385,52385,52385,52385,52385
```

Comment: Where is your FROM clause on your select?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CAST` and `COLLECT` to group it into a collection:

```
SELECT   h.h_spa_id as spa_id,
         h.submit_dt,
         h.oa_ap_date,
         CAST( COLLECT( DISTINCT gl ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST ) AS mygl
FROM     h
         INNER JOIN
         d
         ON ( h.table1_id = d.table2_id )
WHERE    h.next_apprv = 'approverID'
AND      h.table1_id  = table3_id
GROUP BY h.h_spa_id,
         h.submit_dt,
         h.oa_ap_date
ORDER BY h.h_spa_id
```

Then when you use it for subsequent processing the values will be in an array.